# In Objective-C does it make sense to declare a readonly property in a category?

Tags: objective-c

Let's say I have `Tree.h` and `Tree+Extensions.h`. I know that if I declare, in `Tree+Extensions.h` a `@property (nonatomic) NSString *color` and then access it, it will crash, and that I can get something similar to that functionality using `objc_getAssociatedObject` and `objc_setAssociatedObject`.

However, I've also seen this:

```
// Tree+Extensions.h
@interface Tree (Extensions)
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *color;
@end

// Tree+Extensions.m
@implementation Tree (Extensions)
- (NSString *)color {
    return @"green";
}
@end
```

Notice that the property in the category is declared as `readonly` and that the accessor method is returning something that can be calculated.

I've seen this code working, but was wondering why would this be preferable than just declaring the accessor method in the header file.

Comment: for properties you can use the `.` opreator to access them, for methods you cannot.

Comment: @holex Not true. Try it!

Comment: @holex: You can, but you shouldn't

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets, I agree with you, I used the wrong words above, indeed.

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets I've seen Apple's own sample code using property syntax to call a method that's not declared as a property, so it can't be such a bad thing to do.

Comment: @matt: Apple's sample code isn't always the greatest, but in this case it doesn't matter much. Apple does mention some conventions about properties here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150-CH1-SW4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first disregard the fact that this is a category and just talk about this:

```
@interface Tree
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *color;
@end
@implementation Tree
- (NSString *)color {
    return @"green";
}
@end
```

As I understand it, your question is: what's the difference between that and this:

```
@interface Tree
- (NSString *)color;
@end
@implementation Tree
- (NSString *)color {
    return @"green";
}
@end
```

From a completely practical point of view, there is *no* difference. People do get used to declaring properties, but in fact those two declarations have exactly the same effect - namely, in either case, a caller (anyone who has imported the interface) can say `[aTree color]` or `aTree.color`, indifferently. A property usage (`aTree.color`) *is* a method call `[aTree color]`, and vice versa. A caller can *say* `aTree.color` even if only the `color` *method* is declared (not a property). That is why, for example, it is legal (and common) to say `myArray.count`, even though NSArray's `count` is not declared as a property (it's just a method). And, *vice versa*, it is legal (and common) to say `[myViewController navigationController]` even though `navigationController` is declared as a property.

Now, in *most* cases, the reason for declaring a property is in order to get the compiler to synthesize the corresponding instance variable and the corresponding method implementation(s). But none of that is happening *in this case*; there is no instance variable and there is no getter to synthesize (it has been written explicitly).

So, to conclude, let's now return to your original question and sum up: You cannot use a named category (like your `Tree (Extensions)`) to add an instance variable to an existing class. As [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html):

> It’s valid syntax to include a property declaration in a category interface, but it’s not possible to declare an additional instance variable in a category. This means the compiler won’t synthesize any instance variable, nor will it synthesize any property accessor methods.

Well, in this case, you are *not* adding an instance variable to an existing class, and you are *not* trying to synthesize the "getter": the `readonly` property declaration is backed by an *existing* "getter" method which, as you rightly say, calculates the result from whole cloth. Thus, the property declaration, while kind of pointless, is perfectly legal and effective: it just declares the "getter" method.

Comment: Whoever is downvoting this is evidently just ignorant of the facts.

Comment: They probably didn't even read your answer. The question here is subjective anyway since it's basically asking why a certain syntax should be used over another when both are equally fine.

Comment: Well, @Nighthawk441, I think some people do honestly imagine that you can't say `someObject.someProperty` unless `someProperty` is an explicitly declared property. I think _I_ used to think that! But it isn't true and never was; it works if `someProperty` is the name of a method declared as taking no parameters and returning a nonvoid result.

Comment: There is (obviously) a difference between the two declarations: One declares a property and the other declares a method. That in itself is a difference. But there's also a difference in the result: The property can be queried during runtime and returns introspection information. The method does not.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I don't see that. An object is just as introspectable for its methods as for its properties, if that's the kind of thing you're into.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe "One declares a property and the other declares a method. That in itself is a difference" But not _in this case_, where the property is read-only and neither an instance variable nor a getter method is to be synthesized.

Comment: @matt Your post is about calling syntax. I wanted to point out that there's more to it than only syntax: While code talks to the compiler it also talks to the developer reading your code after you. There's a subtle difference between a method declaration and a property. Another more practical difference is the `property_copyAttribute*` set of APIs. It returns much more detailed runtime information than there is for methods. You can, for example, query the exact type of a property and get `NSString` instead of only `id`, like for methods. This also works for properties declared in categories.

Answer (score 1):

With the code that you wrote, even from within the class you can't call `setColor:`, which can make sense when you want to return something that is not backed by an ivar (calculated for example), and that you don't want to expose to the outside world.

**Answer:** This is preferred because you don't need access to this property from outside the class.